# What is $W_1 + W_2$ if $W_1\subset W_2$?

Tags: vector-spaces

If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are vector subspaces. What is  $W_1 + W_2$ if  $W_1\subset W_2$ ?

I have assumed that $v\in W_1 + W_2$, and proved that $(W_1 + W_2) \subset W_2$? Is this the correct answer or am I only half way through the solution?

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by $\oplus$.

Answer (score 4):

The set of all sums $w_1+w_2$ are all in $W_2$. 
The reverse containment is also trivial. 
So the answer is $W_2$.

Comment: Can you please help in how the reverse containment can be proved?

Comment: $w_2\in W_2\implies 0+w_2\in W_1+W_2.$

Comment: @mfl but this does not use the fact that $W_1 \subset W_2$

Comment: Of course it does. Otherwise, how would you know that $w_1+w_2\in W_2$? This is guaranteed by the fact that both of them are in $W_2$.

Comment: It is not necessary to show that $W_2\subset W_1+W_2.$

Comment: @A.Pongrácz The OP refers to $W_2\subset W_1+W_2.$

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I thought "this" refered to my answer, not your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: What is the definition of the direct sum $U+V$?

Comment: dimension is not mentioned in question.

Comment: But @mvw did not mention the dimension.

Answer (score 1):

If $W_1 \subset W_2$, then we actually cannot write $W_1 \oplus W_2$, because this does not fit the **definition of $\oplus$**. If we talk about $W_1 + W_2$, then by definition this is just $W_2$ by definition of $+$ between vector subspaces.

Comment: It really depends on the definition. For example $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$ is usually taken to be $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @copper.hat Is this one the so called "outer direct sum"? In the OP, $W_1, W_2$ are given as subspaces, so I assume that we are dealing with the "inner direct sum". But nevertheless you are right about this. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. I use the notation the way you do, my point is just that it depends on what $\oplus$ means to the OP.